# Java Jackson ObjectMapper Inheritance issue

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, json-serialization

```
public interface Vehicle {
    public default String getFourWheel() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Four Wheel not applicable");
    }

    public default String getTwoWheel() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Two Wheel not applicable");
    }
}

public class Bike implements Vehicle {
    private String twoWheel;    
    
    @Override
    public String getTwoWheel() {
        return twoWheel;
    }
    
    public void setTwoWheel(String twoWheel) {
        this.twoWheel = twoWheel;
    }
}

@Test
public void test_jacksonInheritance() throws JsonProcessingException {
    Bike bike = new Bike();
    bike.setTwoWheel("Two Wheeler");
    
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_ABSENT);
    objectMapper.writeValueAsString(bike);
}
```

objectMapper invokes getFourWheel(in interface) and thus throws RuntTimeException: Four Wheel not applicable.

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Four Wheel not applicable (through reference chain: Bike["fourWheel"])

"com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:688)

How can I stop objectMapper from not invoking getFourWheel as this is not required in Bike class.

Comment: The second approach in the linked Q&A should be the best for you here.

Comment: Thanks Tom, For me third approach is least intrusive as I don't want to add annotations to the existing POJOs. 3. Configure ObjectMapper to set custom JacksonAnnotationIntrospector